# Problem with MySQL join query

Tags: mysql, join

I just cant seem to get my head around this problem, so thought I would ask it here.
The system I'm making is a system where farmers can claim subsidy for the crops / animals. Each farmer is allocated to a specific region. What I need to do is to get the total claims made by each region. Here's my tables:
[image]

So what I need to do again is to take the sum of total from the claims table but group that by region. I already know how to do it for one specific region, but I would like to select all the regions in one query.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
      farmer.region_id,
      sum( claims.total ) TotalClaims
   from 
      claims
         join farmer
           on claims.farmer_id = farmer.id
         join regions
           on farmer.region_id = regions.id
   group by
      farmer.region_id
```